# Is it possible to somehow use the arrow-keys in Gnome 3 to navigate through the opened windows?

Tags: keyboard, gnome, navigation

When pressing the super(windows)-key.

I probably would need an extension for it, i suppose. Its qute annoying atm as I always have to switch between using the keyboard with 2 hands and the touchpad + keyboard.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)